# How to access RDP Active X AdvancedSettings2 using PytQT5 QAxWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, activex, remote-desktop

I am trying to implemente a remote desktop client using PyQt5 QAxWidget to expose an MsRdpClient10NotSafeForScripting ActiveX object.

The connection works but I can't figure how to access the AdvancedSettings2 interface.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    RDP_Widget  = QAxWidget()
    # https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/TermServ/msrdpclient10notsafeforscripting.md
    RDP_Widget.setControl('{A0C63C30-F08D-4AB4-907C-34905D770C7D}')
    RDP_Widget.setProperty('Server', '192.168.33.10')
    #print(RDP_Widget.AdvancedSettings2()) <- AttributeError: 'QAxWidget' object has no attribute 'AdvancedSettings2'
    RDP_Widget.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 600)
    RDP_Widget.show()
    RDP_Widget.Connect()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer with help from ChatGPT:

```py
    rdp_advanced_settings = RDP_Widget.querySubObject("AdvancedSettings2")
    rdp_advanced_settings.setProperty("SmartSizing", True)
```